# How should I run a .java or a .class file using nohup?

Tags: java, nohup

For the first time I'm just playing around with `nohup` on top of an Ubuntu server. I read few docs about `nohup` and got to know about the running commands with options such as `nohup ./server.sh &`.

What I want to know is that, how should I be running a .java file using `nohup`? Is there a particular way? Or should I be converting it to a `jar` and then run it as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323690/run-a-java-program-in-backend).Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How were you running it without `nohup`?

Comment: @MichaelHomer I had to run that particular class as a background process, so that's why I thought of using `nohup`.

Comment: That isn't an answer to my question. You can [edit] your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nohup is a command which makes another command safe from hup signals. Assuming you already know how it behaves, you can run java file as:

```
nohup ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java YourClass &
```

Or

```
nohup ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java -cp ${CLASSPATH} YourClass &
```

In case of jar

```
nohup ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java -jar Yourjar.jar &
```

Note: The last & sign is not the part of nohup. This is to make your process to run in background.